# Sync directories from iMac & MacBook . What is the recommended method?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, data-synchronization

I like to sync directories from my Imac & MacBook . What is the recommended method?

Comment: I'm looking rather for an in-house and not a cloud (e.g. dropbox) solution

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods for syncing things across computers. If you do not mind having all of your directories within a certain superdirectory, and do not have too much stuff to sync, Dropbox is a great and incredibly easy way to go. If you have a lot of data or want to sync directories from anywhere on your computer, BitTorrent Sync is a quick and secure method for syncing data.